# Using a POCO class as a domain class, but with custom link getters and setters?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, poco

I recently learned that it's a good idea (when working with Entity Framework) to design it code-first, with POCO classes that are also mixed with original domain class logic.

So I decided to use this new idea. Before (as an example) I had a POCO class called `DatabasePerson` and a domain class called `Person`. I am now trying to merge these into one, so that I can let Entity Framework manage my repository better, and manage changes to the domain layer easier.

Now, in my `DatabasePerson` POCO class, I have a link to a `DatabaseAccount` POCO class. Similarly, my `Person` domain class has a link to a `Account` domain class.

In Entity Framework, to allow for lazy loading of these types of links, I declare the link properties virtual (as in the `DatabasePerson` class), like so:

`public virtual DatabaseAccount Account { get; set; }`

**However, what if I want to change how the account is set or get, and how exceptions are handled when attempting to set it to `null`? How can I make sure that this won't conflict with anything that Entity Framework adds to the table?**

Here's my domain class' link:

```
public Account Account {
    get {
        //maybe do some other stuff here.
        return account;
    }
    set {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        account = value;

        //maybe do some other stuff here.
    }
}
```

**I want to somehow keep this form of customizability, but also have lazy loading. Is that possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy loading conflicts with the concepts of Domain Driven Design, especially that of [Aggregates](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html).  Retrieving and updating an aggregate from a repository should be a single operation.  The aggregate needs to be complete as per the specification in the ubiquitous language. Introducing lazy loading breaks this rule as the aggregate isn't complete (or perhaps this is an indication that you haven't defined your aggregates properly).

In addition to the above, you are also violating one of the core principles in DDD; you are designing your domain with a strong influence of technical concerns (Entity Framework, databases, lazy loading, etc).  Introducing these infrastructural 'leaks' will constrain the way in which you make design decisions.  Entities and Value Objects form the absolute core of your domain.  They are real-world objects that interact with each other.  Persistence ignorance is key to designing a good domain model.

I will give you a short example of an aggregate, but you need to do more reading if you wish to better grasp this concept.

Let's say that you have decided that the `Order` entity is the root of an aggregate which includes `Order` and `OrderLine` (an `Order` can have 1 or many `OrderLine` entities).  This decision can be based off many reasons, some being:

- An `OrderLine` has no need to be retrieved or referenced independently from its `Order`
- An `Order` should be responsible for changes to its OrderLine 'collection'
- An `Order` and its `OrderLines` should be transactionally consistent

When fetching `Order` from a repository, this aggregate will be formed in a single unit of work.  All `OrderLines` will be fetching with their Order and returned.  When saving or updating, the aggregate is also persisted in a single unit of work.  This ensures that all of the entities (and their relationships) remain consistent and that no 'business rules' are violated.

In your case, a `Person` and their `Accounts` should most likely not belong in a single aggregate.  I assume that you would need to access a person's accounts without needing to retrieve the person itself (perhaps using identity).  I assume that you will want to reference to a specific account from outside of the aggregate (only aggregate roots can be referenced from outside of an aggregate).  I also assume that an `Account` can change independently of `Person`.  Perhaps another reason why you wouldn't want it to belong in the Person aggregate is due to performance reasons (yes, sometimes we have to be pragmatic and not purist!). All of the above entirely depends on your requirements.

Personally I believe in separating your data entities (generally a direct mapping from your database using Entity Framework or some other persistence tool) and your domain entities/value objects.  This lets you design your domain in complete isolation of database-related structures, frameworks and constraints.

Comment: With Entity Framework, the retrieving and updating of an aggregate is exactly one operation. And you don't have to save all the time, you can save when you want to. With this in mind, do you still have the same opinion on the matter? It should be noted that Person and Account are not real objects in my database. I just made them up as an example.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen It's not an opinion, this is how DDD works, domain first, db doesn't exist. The Domain has no clue you're using EF and the Domain should be identical regardless of ORM or if you're using a db in the first place.

Comment: I just thought that was the point of POCO. To make it easier to integrate with the domain classes. In a DDD world, how can I store things in the database?

Comment: Also, with DDD in mind, what is then the proper way of using Entity Framework together with your domain classes?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen:  In the DDD world, there is no such thing as a database!  Ok, in the real world with time and stakeholder pressure, that is a strong statement :). Regardless, it is important to try not think about databases and relational data structures when domain modeling.  You could have some EF concrete implementations (in a ninfrastructure layer) of your `IRepository` interfaces which reside in the domain. These repository interfaces deal with domain entities (aggregate, to be precise).  Your EF classes should map between your EF data entities and the domain models.